# how to add video from database without url?

Tags: c#

my name is omer and i m a student. i created a website and i wnat that the user will  upload a video.
i used a ole object to add db and i succed but im having  trouble to adding the video from db to the website. i dont want to save the file in folder and than use url. is it posiblle? 
the code:
App_Data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public class MyVideoHelper
{
    public MyVideoHelper()
    {

    }

    //הפונקציה מקבלת מסלול של קובץ ומחזירה את הקובץ מומר לבייטים
    public  byte[] ConvertFileToByte(Stream file)
    {
        byte[] video = null;

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file);
        video = br.ReadBytes((int)(file.Length));

        return video;
    }
    public FileStream ConvertByteToFile( byte[] file)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(file);
        FileStream filestream = stream as FileStream;
        return filestream;
    }


}
```

the sapx.cs

```
MyVideoHelper x = new MyVideoHelper();
            string hero3 = Request.Form["hero3"];
            if (Session["loggedIn"] != "true")
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('You Are not SignIN!');</script>");
                return;
            }
            if ((video2.PostedFile != null) && (video2.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                Stream fs = video2.PostedFile.InputStream;
                string command = "INSERT INTO videos (hero, file) VALUES( '" + hero3 + "','" + x.ConvertFileToByte(fs) + "')";
                MyAdoHelper.DoQuery("omerwatchdb.accdb", command);

            }

            string sql = "SELECT file FROM videos";
            DataTable info = MyAdoHelper.ExecuteDataTable("omerwatchdb.accdb", sql);
            string omer;
            omer = info.Rows[2][0].ToString();
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(omer);
             vid = x.ConvertByteToFile(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to insert a video file into a database (and you should probably not), then you should treat it as binary data, i.e. a BLOB column. To insert data you should use "parameterized query" where specify the data for the SQL command separate from command itself.

you could follow an [example on how to add a image file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/inserting-an-image-from-a-file). The process will be identical for a video. [And here is an article on how to retrieve the data.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-binary-data)